# SpringBoot: can't create war with maven: Unable to find main class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, war

I have a SpringBoot project with the war and ear module, that I build using maven ( a build automation tool used primarily for Java projects.) and IntelliJ IDEA
This is my pom.xml of the war project

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.bendiciones</groupId>
        <artifactId>bendiciones-parent</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>bendiciones-war</artifactId>
    <name>bendiciones war</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bendicionesbendiciones</groupId>
            <artifactId>bendiciones</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>bendiciones</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.bendiciones.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <scm>
        <tag>bendiciones-parent-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</tag>
    </scm>
</project>
```

But when I build the class I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project bendiciones-war: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project bendiciones-war: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
```

Even the class exist in the project

Comment: You don't need to define mainClass and goals if you are packaging your spring boot app as war file

Comment: If not specified the first compiled class found that contains a 'main' method will be used.

Comment: What is your use case here ? do you have multiple main methods ?

Comment: Could you please share your directory structure and the entire pom file for furthur analysis.

Comment: Also share your class with main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your main(starterApplication) class. The "Main-Class" in the manifest is actually controlled by the "layout" property of the [Spring Boot plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html).

```
    <build>
       <plugins>
        ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
                <configuration>    
                     <mainClass>com.your.starter.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And you need to check `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
Start-Class: com.your.starter.Application
```

[The Executable War File Structure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html)

```
example.war
 |
 +-META-INF
 |  +-MANIFEST.MF
 +-org
 |  +-springframework
 |     +-boot
 |        +-loader
 |           +-<spring boot loader classes>
 +-WEB-INF
    +-classes
    |  +-com
    |     +-mycompany
    |        +-project
    |           +-YourClasses.class
    +-lib
    |  +-dependency1.jar
    |  +-dependency2.jar
    +-lib-provided
       +-servlet-api.jar
       +-dependency3.jar
```

Or Build using parent and child relationships.

```
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: spring boot doesn't require maven-war-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin is enough to generate a war file, all you need is to define packaging as war.

Answer (score 0):

You are packaging your application in WAR, that indicates your application is Web Application. Thus, please check or add below important Spring Boot dependency in pom.xml for same:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I've added this dependency with the same result :-(